# Self Learning - Moonshine beyond the Monster

Tags: self-learning, book-recommendation

**EDIT:** I tried to introduce some of the parts that I could use extra reading in the below list, and changed the final question to be more specific to the list.

I am working on a individual study as an undergraduate, and my topic of interest is about number theory and physics, and in particular the following book [Moonshine beyond the Monster](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/moonshine-beyond-the-monster/CAD32EB4694E501D0B656696AE69EDFF) attracted me and was advised me the most. The thing is , even though I have undergraduate level understanding of algebra, Galois theory, complex analysis and real analysis, along with a bit higher level topology (Munkres) and differential geometry (Lee's) background, I think some supplementary material along this book would be very helpful. More specifically, a course related to this subject would be very helpful.

This book contains subjects as :

- Modular forms

- Kac-Moody algebras
- CFT and TQFT
- Vertex Operator algebras

What would be some supplemental resources for subjects listed above from this book?

Answer (score 1):

I think you have bitten off more than you can chew, let alone digest. That said, this might help: https://wstein.org/edu/2010/414/projects/padvorac.pdf

> Introduction
>
> As noted in the abstract, the end motivation here, in
> simple, is to develop the definitions needed to actually understand
> the very peculiar key observation that brought about “moonshine”
> theory, a recent development interweaving number theory, algebra, and
> to a lesser extent, physics. By taking this admittedly very shallow
> approach to introducing modular forms, it is sure that a large portion
> of their depth will be lost; as an undergraduate research project,
> this is nearly bound to happen regardless, as many needed ideas are in
> the toolboxes of graduate algebra. That is the downside of what I’ll
> be presenting here. The upshot is that it will be an
> undergraduate-accessible introduction to these topics, and a small
> glimpse into the motivation of the Monstrous Moonshine theory and conjectures.

Comment: Yes, indeed I don't expect to understand everything very well, but this is a bit extracurricular that i can afford some imperfection.